# PHP variable in JavaScript data

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using "[Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/)" to make a chart, I want to use PHP variables in that chart, though it does not seem to work - the chart disapears when I try.

```
<script>
        var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
        var lineChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "Hit Counter last year",
                    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data: [<?php echo $count; ?>, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
                }
            ]
        }
    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
    }
</script>
```

The JavaScript is seperate from the PHP, the whole .php file can be found [here](http://hastebin.com/gorurirumu.xml)

Am I trying to 'get' the variable in the wrong way?

Comment: What is not working ? Can you check `data` array in source ?

Comment: That would only work if you are trying to dynamically create that javascript code on the server side. That will _not_ work on the client side, since that variable does not exist there.

Comment: please console log your data

Comment: Are you parsing JavaScript through PHP?  Usually, there are better ways.  What is rendered?  I expect it is not what you expect.

Comment: Edited the post with more information :)

Comment: Show us what `console.log(lineChartData.datasets[0].data)` gives you

Comment: Var count = <?=$count?>; count = parstInt(count); and this count variable in chart array after using parseint ..... try it and share result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that you should paste your php code before js.
Then you are trying to access variable $count in js it has empty value;

```
<script>
    console.log(<?php echo $count; ?>);    //value is ""
</script>


<?php
$count = 50;
?>

<script>
    console.log(<?php echo $count; ?>);  // value is 50
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's because $count not have values.

Try to declare $count at line 1.

```
$count=0
```

Comment: Did you read the post? I clearly did not miss closing tags? `<?php echo $count; ?>`

Comment: @iversen Sorry i didnt see, its from mobile. Maybe you should declare $count at line 1. Since you not declare it it will return empty. Or put your php code to assign count above <script> tag